# Conditional Probability among multiple envents

Tags: probability

The answer provided by the lecturer says:

$$P\{a,c|b\} = P\{a|b\}P\{c|a\}$$

Is it true? I do know which law it applies.

Comment: It's called the "chain rule" (though it's different from the chain rules in calculus)

Comment: I know "chain rule", but I do not how to apply it in the problem.

Comment: What is the problem?  You seem to have forgotten to type it.

Comment: How to apply it in the formula above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property does not always hold. When it holds, it is called the *conditional independence of $b$ and $c$ conditionally on $a$* since the identity can be rewritten as
$$
P\{b,c|a\} = P\{b|a\}P\{c|a\}.
$$

Comment: Do you have any reference related to the property?